# DFExecutorUserError java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm collecting data from an SQL database then I fill an archive in the blob with extension "Avro", then I get this Avro and insert into my stage table in DW. It was working perfectly a couple days ago, but now I'm receiving this error when Datafactory reads the blob archive to sink at the DW stage.

Can somebody help?

```
{"message":"java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map. Details:java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.Map","failureType":"SystemError","target":"stage table name","errorCode":"DFExecutorUserError"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just call to Microsoft and figureout thats a bug with azure dataflow, basicaly the data flow is broke when you call a dataflow using Azure KeyVault to autenticate in repos,
i change my authentication to manually and worked...
the Microsoft is working to fix this issue.